# Email downloaded with python imaplib not saved to disc correctly. How to fix?

Tags: python, email, imap, email-attachments, imaplib

I am writing python code to download email attachments. A particular case that we are struggling with is when one email is attached to another. In other words, when an email ([reference example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19aCJqkYKXTjzgVoDQS88KXvpjSiOrp_Y/view?usp=sharing)) contains a `.eml` attachment, with a structure as such that:

```
Outer email
    Outer Subject, Body and other headers
    Regular attachment 1
    Regular attachment 2
    .eml attachment
        Inner Subject, Body and other headers
        Inner Attachment 1
        Inner Attachment 2
```

The script below successfully downloads all the attachments of a given email, including .eml attachments. However, when I open the .eml file that that is downloaded with this script, I get [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12N8FhfpJ1wZjpPfYZHC3FGCAJYg-Z4K4/view?usp=sharing), with the following structure:

```
Opened Email
   Blank Subject, Body and other headers 
   Attached Email
        Inner Subject, Body and other headers
        Inner Attachment 1
        Inner Attachment 2
```

In some cases it even nests once more than the example above. However, I expected [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13NOBnX5niQio3iZ5_X91oblZ181BRdhK/view?usp=sharing), with the structure:

```
Opened Email
    Inner Subject, Body and other headers
    Inner Attachment 1
    Inner Attachment 2
```

Which is what you will get when you download an email using a email client like Outlook or Gmail.

Please can you help me understand why this is happening and how to get the expected result rather than the current one?

```
server, port, user, password = "imap.gmail.com", 993, "jon.snow@the_wall.ws", "Ygr!tt3"

import imaplib
from email import policy, header, message_from_bytes
from os import path

# connect to mailbox
mail_client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server, port)
mail_client.login(user, password)

# retrieve target mail
mail_client.select('INBOX')
mails = mail_client.search(None, '(SUBJECT "test mail saving")')
mail_ids = mails[1][0].decode("utf-8").split(' ')
mail_id = mail_ids[0]
ret, data = mail_client.fetch(mail_id, '(RFC822)')
msg = message_from_bytes(data[0][1], policy=policy.default)

# save all mail attachments to disc
for part in msg.iter_parts():
    print(part.get('Content-Type'))
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
    if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
        continue

    filename, encoding = header.decode_header(part.get_filename())[0]
    att_path = path.join('c:/temp/', filename)

    fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
    if filename.split('.')[-1] == 'eml':
        fp.write(part.as_bytes(policy=policy.SMTP))
    else:
        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
    fp.close()
```

Comment: I see two `continue` in your main loop, is one of them getting hit?

Comment: @MarkRansom: yes, the first one is hit once for the example case, but that is expected (it is to prevent trying to save things that are not actually attachments).

Comment: why this is happening - cause it nested :D  https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/blob/master/examples/email_parse_eml_attachments.py#L13

Comment: @Vladimir thanks! Could you elaborate a little? I've looked at the shared code, but not sure what to make of it...